keycloak skips OTP when a user creates an account
We want to force the user to use OTP when it tries to login to a specific client.
What we have done so far.
We made a copy of the "browser" authentication flow and named it "browser otp"
then changed "Conditional OTP" to Required in the new flow.
In the authentication flow overreides of the specific client we configured the new flow "browser otp" as browser flow.
Now when an existing user tries to login to the client, it is prompted to configure OTP (if not yet)
So far so good.
But the porblem is, we have also an "Create Account" button on the login page, and if a user creates a new account it can do so and is afterwards logged in to the client but without OTP.
How can we force the user to activate OTP even when he comes form account creation?

If you do not want to that user should be able to skip OTP, bind the new "browser otp" as the default browser flow. Then it will be active for ALL clients, not only specific ones.
If that is not possible, be sure that the "Create Account" button uses the correct client-id (and client-secret) afterwards. But that is a security issue, if other (non-otp) browser flow is still active and accessible!!
